# «Как Польша с Израилем горшки побили» — согласование

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые

Вот такое предложение: **Как Польша с Израилем горшки побили**.
Можно ли употребить множественное число?

Answer (score 4):

Полагаю, что так: ***Как Польша с Израилем горшки побили.***

В данном примере согласование определяется смыслом, вкладываемым автором.

(Подробнее - у Розенталя http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-186-skazuemoe-pri-podlezhashchem-tipa-brat-s-sestroy)

Почти наверняка он имел ввиду совместное действие и равную ("равноактивную") роль участников процесса "битья горшков". В таком случае согласование должно быть по **множественному числу**.

Почему именно так, почему действие совместное?

Во-первых, на то наталкивает сам смысл фразеологизма.
Словарь народных поговорок дает три областных значения "битья горшков".
~1. действие, отсылающее к части свадебного обряда (посуду бьют на счастье после первой брачной ночи).
~2. дуться, сердиться на кого-либо
~3. рассориться, прекратить супружеские отношения.
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/18411/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

В общелитературный язык фразеологизм вошел в третьем значении. К тому же первые два
значения очень тяжело осмыслить в данной грамматической схеме (*А. и Б. побили горшки. На чьей свадьбе? На кого дуются? и проч.*).
*А третье значение очевидно*. Польша и Израиль поссорились.

И во-вторых. Очень не хочется тащить сюда политику, но здесь это необходимо. Можно с полной уверенностью утверждать, что материал с подобным заголовком отсылает к дипломатическому конфликту, возникшему после подписания Президентом Польши Анджеем Дудой закона о "сроке давности" реституции. По нему административное решение (в том числе о праве собственности) по истечении 30 лет со дня вынесения не подлежит обжалованию.
Израиль усмотрел в этом ущемление прав жертв холокоста и их потомков, Польша ответила довольно жестко, короче, дипломатические отношения между двумя странами сильно охладели.
И здесь явно два действующих лица.

Итак, с учетом смысла имеем: ***согласование должно идти по множественному числу***.

Answer (score 3):

Тут как раз что нужно. Единственное не подходит.

Но:
*Как охотник с собакой шёл.* || Неоднородность действующих лиц. А в примере со странами они абсолютно однородны.

Update:
Ссора — **взаимное действие** (даже при единственном числе), что указано в словарях.

В такой позиции необходимо единственное число по грамматике:
*Как Польша поссорилась с ИзрАилем.* || Это доказывает, что форма единственного числа тоже допустима.
Почему бы не использовать единственное число и при глаголе в постпозиции? Но логическое ударение необходимо сохранить:
*Как Польша с ИзрАилем поссорилась.* || Корректно. Здесь (как и выше) Польша выступает **инициатором** ссоры (тем, кто её начал), но это не значит, что Израиль ни при чём, он ссорился **на равных**. Ударение нестандартное для такой позиции. Но если ударение будет на глаголе, то единственное число будет некорректным:
*Как Польша с Израилем поссОрилась.*

Проблема в том, что при "горшки побили" ударение выше не подходит:
*Как Польша с ИзрАилем горшки побила.* || Так уже не читается. Корректно только множественное:
*Как Польша с Израилем гОршки побили.*

Answer (score 2):

Множественное число употребить не только можно, но и нужно. Субъектов действия два, Польша и Израиль? Ну и всё!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128648/discussion-on-answer-by----------).

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от того, что желает сказать автор.
Если речь идет об односторонней инициативе Польши (т.е. Израиль ничего такого не хочет), то уместно единственное число:

> Как Польша с Израилем горшки побила.

Если же автор хотел подчеркнуть взаимность ссоры, то тут уместнее множественное число:

> Как Польша с Израилем горшки побили.

Чтобы было проще понять разницу в оттенках, заменим формулировку "горшки побили" на более простую "поссорились". Надеюсь, здесь смысловое отличие будет очевиднее:

> Как Польша с Израилем поссорилась.

> Как Польша с Израилем поссорились.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128647/discussion-on-answer-by-ivan-olshansky--------).

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что в этом предложении нужно учитывать несколько факторов.

Первый. Значение фразеологизма: *бить горшки* — ссориться; *побить горшки* — поссориться.

Второй. Ссора — это, конечно же, конфликт между кем-то (иногда и чем-то), в котором может быть "наезжающий" (инициатор, зачинщик) и обороняющийся (пассивный участник).

Третий. *Польша* — это слово женского рода.

Вот какие **рекомендации** имеются в справочнике Розенталя.

В оборотах, образованных сочетанием «именительный падеж плюс творительный падеж с предлогом **с**» сказуемое может стоять как в форме **множественного**, так и в форме **единственного** числа.

Форма множественного числа сказуемого показывает, что в роли подлежащего выступает **все сочетание**, т. е. действие приписывается двум взаимосвязанным равноправным субъектам, например: *После обеда Лось с Русаковым **пошли** посмотреть склады и магазины* (Т. Семушкин); ***Встали** и Воропаев с Корытовым* (П. Павленко).

Форма единственного числа сказуемого показывает, что подлежащим является только **существительное в именительном падеже**, а существительное в творительном падеже выступает в роли дополнения, обозначая лицо, сопутствующее производителю действия, например: ***Граф** Илья Андреевич в конце января с Наташей и Соней **приехал** в Москву* (Л. Толстой); *...**Пришел Разметнов** с Демкой Ушаковым* (Шолохов).

Иногда играет роль порядок слов в сочетании. Ср.: ***Муж с женой пошли** в театр.* — ***Жена с мужем пошла** в театр* (обычно в рассматриваемых конструкциях при различной родовой принадлежности существительных на первом месте фигурирует более сильный в грамматическом отношении мужской род, например: *отец с матерью, дед с бабкой, мальчик с девочкой*; поэтому выдвижение на первое место существительного в форме женского рода подчеркивает его роль, а отсюда согласование с ним сказуемого).

Итак, рассмотрим *абстрактное* предложение (единое подлежащее [Польша с Израилем], сказуемое — во множественном числе, оба государства — равноправные участники; **/** — знак паузы):
*Политический мир сошел с ума! Я напомню вам, как Москва с Вашингтоном / поруг**а**лись, как Грузия с Азербайджаном / расс**о**рились. Как Польша с Израилем / горшк**и** побили.*

Другое предложение, с другими акцентами (подлежащее — одно существительное, можно сказать, главный герой [И. п., ед. ч., ж. р.], сказуемое — в единственном числе):
*Долго мир будет помнить, как Москв**а** / с Вашингт**о**ном поругалась, как Гр**у**зия / с Азербайдж**а**ном рассорилась. Как П**о**льша / с Изр**а**илем горшки побила.*

[Сказуемое при подлежащем типа «брат с сестрой»](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL/c.2.2.4.html)